# timestamp to date format is not working in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to convert the timestamp value to date format in twig file but I'm getting the following error.

```
{{ form_row(form.startDate)|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (<div><label for="event_setup_startDate"
>   class="required">Start date</label><input
>   type="text" id="event_setup_startDate"
>   name="event_setup[startDate]" required="required"
>   class="datetimepicker" value="1478257800"
>   /></div>) at position 0 (<): Unexpected character")

Comment: You are passing the HTML code generated by the form_row function to the date constructor. Are you using a framework?

Comment: @Matteo. I'm using symfony framework. The datetype is set is string and trying to conver it to datetime format.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the option [format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format) to the DateTime form field, in the form builder as example:

```
$builder->add('startDate', DateType::class, array(
    'format' => 'm/d/Y',
));
```

Or pass to the twig option as example:

```
{{ form_row(form.startDate, {'format': 'm/d/Y'}) }}
```

Hope this help